# D3.js Make the bars of a bar chart clickable (and make them link to an html page with same name as bar)

Tags: d3.js, charts, hyperlink, clickable

I am using the following bar chart template, code mostly unchanged (but with my own tsv file obviously)

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

It works for me, with only one problem:

When I click on the bar for -say- "A", I want to be taken in a page called A.html

How can I do this? I have played with .onclick and .on("click", ...) for a long time, trying to get the name of which bar was clicked, searched for solution internet, nothing.

Please help me out of this, I am stuck... And my project depends on it

Comment: `svg.selectAll(".bar").on("click", function(d){location.replace(d.letter+".html");});`

Comment: Thank you! I wish this was posted as an answer so I could upvote it.

Comment: Yes, JSBob, please post as an answer.

Comment: Kurkosdr, you can upvote comments, as I just did, after 15 RP.